# Where do I find the latest Source Code of Objective-C 2.0 runtime?

Tags: objective-c

Well I guess at http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/ but where exactly? objc4 doesn't sound much like Objective-C 2.0.

Answer (score 3):

If you read the source code in that directory, it sounds a lot like Objective-C 2.0. Based on the included release notes, it appears to be the version from 10.5.

Answer (score 0):

That "4" refers to the build train of the compiler, not the version of the language.